# How can i insert Texview in toolbar and show text from activity ...Just like Facebook notification icon

Tags: android

Hi I am try to set Textview in toolbar and can change text when click on button from activity. Kindly help me to do it or give me any other way to solve this.  Here is my code. I want to increase the number on the textview in toolbar when button press. Actually I am going to add this in my project to show request from another user just like facebook.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnKhP.png]

here is my toolbar XML

```
  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:text="1"
                android:id="@+id/frrequest"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:gravity="center"
android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And this is I am doing from main Activity OnCreate Method to display number when I press the button with increment but the text is not changing.

```
        sendRequest= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsendreq);

        showreq= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.frrequest);

        sendRequest.setOnClickListener(new MyClickListner());

 private class MyClickListner implements View.OnClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            int i= 0;
            i++;

            showreq.setText(i+"");



        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to increase, so if i get it right you need to write this in onClick method:

```
int preValue = Integer.parseInt(showreq.getText());
showreq.setText(++preValue);
```

Waiting for feedback.

Comment: My problem is not to increment ... Problem is that textview is in toolbar.. and i am updating the text from main activity

Answer (score 0):

Of course, nothing is changed because your `i` is always equal `1`. You need to put your `i` as a global value in order to increase it every click like: `private int i = 0`;

If you really need, you can custom your `Toolbar` views:

```
LayoutInflater mInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
View customView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.toolbar_custom_view, null);
toolbar.addView(mCustomView);
```

In this case, you can fully control your right part of your `Toolbar` (except the `hamburger` icon in left part).